# Making DAX calculated table respond to filters on other table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a DAX table "Sumtable" that calculates the the number of rows in "Maintable" for two cases: (1) all rows in Maintable and (2) the subset of rows where Cat = "A".

```
Sumtable = {
    ("Full set", COUNTROWS(Maintable)),
    ("Subset", COUNTROWS(FILTER(Maintable, Maintable[Cat] = "A")))
}
```

I want to viz Sumtable and make it respond to filter settings on Maintable. For example when I select Maintable[Sex] = "Male" the totals in Sumtable should reflect that. What is the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: Calculated tables cannot be dynamically responsive to filters since they are only calculated when the model is initially loaded or refreshed. You need to use measures for dynamically responsive calculations.

Answer (score 1):

> For example when I select Maintable[Sex] = "Male" the totals in Sumtable should reflect that.

Just make this two measures instead of a calculated table.

If you want these measures to appear under Sometable, you can create a one-row, one-hidden-column table with two measures, instead of two calculated columns.

And when you hide all the non-measure columns on a table it becomes a "[Measure Table](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=powerbi%20measures%20table)" with a differentiated icon.

Comment: Thanks, solved it with this: https://www.analytics-tuts.com/bar-chart-using-measures-in-power-bi/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this: analytics-tuts.com/bar-chart-using-measures-in-power-bi